# How to avoid shared_ptr ambiguity? (stl vs boost)

Tags: c++, ambiguity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is ‘using namespace std;’ considered a bad practice in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

I've used `stl`'s `shared_ptr` many places in my code and I have used the following `using` statement anywhere that I have used `shared_ptr`:

```
using namespace std::tr1;
```

Now I need to use `boost::bimap`. So I have to include the following header file in my code:

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
```

As soon as I include the `bimap` header file, the `shared_ptr` type becomes ambiguous, and I have to change all usages of `shared_ptr` to `std::tr1::shared_ptr`. Since this makes my code ugly, I am looking for a way to avoid this ambiguity without needing to declare `shared_ptr` everywhere with a fully qualified name. I was thinking of using `typedef` for `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, but maybe there are better ways too. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: So you have a using declaration for boost as well?

Comment: And we finally see why `using` directives are a scourge upon the nation. Just. Say. No.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply do not introduce it. avoid the general `using namespace ...`

Answer (score 5):

How about the following:

```
using shared_ptr = std::tr1::shared_ptr;
```

However, the correct answer would actual be to not use the `using namespace ...` statement, or only use it to create namespace aliases.

By the way, you know that `std::tr1` is obselete since C++11 became standardised last year?

Comment: I know but due to some limitations, I cannot switch to C++11 yet.

Comment: and the above `using` does not work: `error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘share_ptr’` 
`error: expected ‘;’ before ‘=’ token`

Comment: @Meysam What compiler and what version of it are you using? It may be that it doesn't support the new type aliases yet.

Comment: g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1

Comment: @FredOverflow Hrm... share or shared... does it really matter? ;)

Comment: Template aliases are not supported until g++ 4.7 IIRC.

Comment: This won't work in most compilers